# Why does this list implementation take more space than stl list?

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl, iar

I'm using IAR as compiler for embedded project. I'm trying to introduce some templates for basic types like list, but each STL list object created increases code size by about 200 bytes relatively to our current C style implementation.
I tried to implement a small portion of the STL list myself hoping to get a smaller code footprint, but ended up being more heavy than the full STL list.
Am I doing something horribly wrong in my usage of templates?

Thanks

P.S. Please note that the code is untested so it may contain dragons.

```
#ifndef __LINK_LIST_HPP__
#define __LINK_LIST_HPP__

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T> class list
{
private:
    struct LinkListElement
    {
        T payload;
        LinkListElement* next;
        LinkListElement* prev;
    };
public:

    class iterator
    {
        // Need access to LinkListElement struct
        friend class list;
    public:
        iterator() : m_cur_item(NULL){}

        iterator(LinkListElement* elem) : m_cur_item(elem){}

        iterator(const iterator& other) : m_cur_item(other.m_cur_item){}

        ~iterator(){}

        iterator& operator=(const iterator& other)
        {
            m_cur_item = other.m_cur_item;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& other) const
        {
            // Compare by position, ignoring the payload contents when comparing iterators.
            return  (m_cur_item->next == other.m_cur_item->next) &&
                    (m_cur_item->prev == other.m_cur_item->prev);
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) const
        {
            return !(*this == other);
        }

        // Prefix increment operator.
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            increment();
            return *this;
        }

        // Postfix increment operator.
        iterator operator++(int)
        {
            iterator copy(*this);
            increment();
            return copy;
        }

        // Prefix decrement operator.
        iterator& operator--()
        {
            decrement();
            return *this;
        }

        // Postfix decrement operator.
        iterator operator--(int)
        {
            iterator copy(*this);
            decrement();
            return copy;
        }

        T& operator*()
        {
            // Just so we won't crash, but behavior is undefined.
            if (m_cur_item == NULL)
            {
                return dummy;
            }

            return m_cur_item->payload;
        }

        T* operator->()
        {
            if (m_cur_item == NULL)
            {
                return NULL;
            }

            return &(m_cur_item->payload);
        }

    private:

        void increment()
        {
            if (m_cur_item == NULL || m_cur_item->next == NULL)
            {
                return;
            }

            m_cur_item = m_cur_item->next;
        }

        void decrement()
        {
            if (m_cur_item == NULL || m_cur_item->prev == NULL)
            {
                return;
            }

            m_cur_item = m_cur_item->prev;
        }

        LinkListElement* m_cur_item;
        static T dummy;

    };

    // Need access to internal LinkListElement pointer
    friend class iterator;

    list()
    {
        // Add sentinel to mark end of list.
        m_tail = new LinkListElement;
        m_tail->next = m_tail;
        m_tail->prev = m_tail;
        m_head = m_tail;
    }

    ~list()
    {
        // Clear entire list except for sentinel
        clear();

        // Destroy sentinel
        delete m_tail;
        m_head = NULL;
        m_tail = NULL;
    }

    T& back()
    {
        // empty list with only sentinel. Result of back() is undefined
        if (empty())
        {
            // TODO: Show some debug error
        }

        return m_tail->prev->payload;
    }

    T& front()
    {
        if (empty())
        {
            // TODO: Show some debug error
        }

        // m_head is always defined even if list is empty
        return m_head->payload;
    }

    size_t size()
    {
        return m_count;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        // head == tail means the list is empty
        return m_head == m_tail;
    }

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(m_head);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(m_tail);
    }

    iterator insert(iterator position, const T& payload)
    {
        // Validate position by finding it in our list
        iterator find = begin();
        while (find != end() && find != position)
        {
            ++find;
        }

        if (find == end())
        {
            // TODO: Show some debug error
            return position;
        }

        return insert_before(find.m_cur_item, payload);
    }

    void push_back(const T& payload)
    {
        insert_before(m_tail, payload);
    }

    void push_front(const T& payload)
    {
        insert_before(m_head, payload);
    }

    iterator erase(iterator position)
    {
        // Validate position by finding it in our list
        iterator find = begin();
        while (find != end() && find != position)
        {
            ++find;
        }

        if (find == end())
        {
            // TODO: Show some debug error
            return position;
        }

        return remove_at(find.m_cur_item);

    }

    //iterator erase(iterator first, iterator last);    // Implement only if needed
    void pop_back()
    {
        if (!empty())
        {
            // Don't remove the sentinel
            remove_at(m_tail->prev);
        }
    }

    void pop_front()
    {
        if (!empty())
        {
            remove_at(m_head);
        }
    }

    void remove(const T& value)
    {
        iterator iter = begin();

        while (iter != end())
        {
            iterator remove = iter++;
            if (*remove == value)
            {
                remove_at(remove.m_cur_item);
            }
        }
    }

    void clear()
    {
        while (!empty())
        {
            pop_back();
        }
    }

private:

    iterator insert_before(LinkListElement* existing, const T& payload)
    {
        // Allocate memory and save the element
        LinkListElement* new_elem = new LinkListElement;

        // For classes types (not pointer to object) this should invoke copy constructor
        new_elem->payload = payload;
        new_elem->prev = existing->prev;
        new_elem->next = existing;
        existing->prev = new_elem;
        ++m_count;

        if (existing == m_head)
        {
            m_head = new_elem;
        }

        return iterator(new_elem);
    }

    iterator remove_at(LinkListElement* to_remove)
    {
        // Allocate memory and save the element
        LinkListElement* prev = to_remove->prev;
        LinkListElement* next = to_remove->next;
        prev->next = next;
        next->prev = prev;
        --m_count;

        if (to_remove == m_head)
        {
            m_head = next;
        }

        delete to_remove;

        return iterator(prev);
    }

    LinkListElement* m_head;
    LinkListElement* m_tail;
    uint32_t         m_count;
};

template <typename T> T list<T>::iterator::dummy;

#endif
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. How does adding more code to my implementation will reduce the code footprint?
I only implemented the basic methods for now, for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you talking about code size or run time size of the list data structure ?

Comment: For one thing, you default construct a `T` and then assign to it. That could result in something different. You should use placement new or, at least, a sensible constructor for your `LinkListElement` struct.

Comment: @Arunmu Perhaps I wasn't clear enough with my question. I'm trying to understand why my code takes more space than the full STL implementation. I have no doubt that this presented implementation is nowhere near STL list. It's not intended to be.

Comment: You're still not being clear. What does "takes more space" mean? Larger code? Larger working set when running?

Comment: @shayst Ah..ok I see.

Comment: @Arunmu Like I said in my question, I'm taking about code size.

Comment: Then the answer is probably just something like "your code is not as heavily optimized for your platform as the supplied STL is". Why would you expect a smaller code footprint? You have lots of stuff the STL doesn't have and that has a cost.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not sure how what you're suggesting will decrease code size. Could you please explain?

Comment: I suspect the standard library implementation doesn't bother checking for undefined behavior and probably doesn't return a dummy object to mask it. If your going to take any action, failing noticeably is better than hiding it.

Comment: @shayst Remove all the things your implementation has that the STL doesn't, such as `dummy`, the checks for invalid accesses, and so on. Those things aren't free -- that's why the STL doesn't have them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I haven't implemented most of STL features, like allocators, traits and such.
What's more, the code I write is very similar to our own C style list implementation, so I can't see why it should take a lot more code unless I'm doing something wrong with the template.

Comment: @shayst It takes more code than the STL because it does stuff the STL doesn't do. Yes, the STL does some things your code doesn't do, *but you aren't using any of those things*, so they don't matter. But your code has stuff the STL doesn't have *that you are using*. You pay for what you use. You use more, you pay more.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll remove those and retest. It will be surprising though if it's more than 100 bytes per object, but I'll test.

Comment: What you're doing horribly wrong is assuming that there's something wrong with your platform that you can easily fix. There's likely nothing wrong and thus nothing to fix. If you add more features, you will pay for them.

Comment: Particularly in template programming much of the source code doesn't make it into compiled code, it's just scaffolding that gives the compiler rules to force on the programmer.

Comment: @shayst Outside of this question, don't you have a standard library implementation to use?

Comment: @Arunmu We do have, like I said, we can't use it since the code footprint price is too high.

Comment: @shayst *Am I doing something horribly wrong in my usage of templates?* -- The persons responsible for the `std::list` implementation are not amateurs, and many are some of the best programmers in the business.  They keep an eye not only on proper implementation, but code size and also the platform / compiler they're writing the implementation for.  It is much more than just getting up and writing any code they feel is "ok".

Comment: @shayst Are you talking actually about the [STL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info) or did you mean the c++ standard library?

Comment: @shayst Well, I am more confused now. Though, I definitely like to get the numbers, but if you need to reduce the code size (even with the std library) then you will have to trade off speed for encoding type as runtime parameter.

Comment: @shayst -- Look at the `std::list` code for any compiler -- does it look at all as simple as your implementation?  Yet it comes in smaller in size.  C++ doesn't work the same way it does (most of the time) in `C`, where the more complex looking code means it is larger in size.  This is where a lot of `C` programmers are flummoxed with, and that is that proper use of C++ idioms, even they seem more "wordy", results in a smaller code size.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I generally agree with what you said. I have no doubt that if I'd have to implement the full STL list, there's no way in hell I'll do it more efficiently than those who wrote the original list, with their skill and peer review processes. I was hoping getting a significantly smaller subset of the functionality would result in a small code footprint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code has all kinds of features and checks that the STL doesn't have. So it makes sense that you would wind up with more code.

Yes, the STL has lots of features your code doesn't have. But you aren't using any of them, so they don't show up in your code footprint. The STL is designed using templates so that you don't pay for what you don't use.

It's unlikely you can improve on the STL. If you need to add features, add them. You don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: So you are saying just creating a list of an int object by template vs a specialized code to handle link list with pointers will differ by about 200 bytes? Is that the minimum price of templates?

Comment: No, the templates are (probably) free. It's all your extra checks that are costing you. (This is why the STL does so well. Because it uses templates, you don't pay for what you don't use.) You also have a lot of small issues, see my comments about not using placement new or constructing the inner objects correctly.

Comment: I'll rephrase. If I take C style list and recreate it with STL template one to one, I get increased code footprint of about 200 bytes. Without using any bells and whistles. Just the very basic push, pop, front, back, end() begin()  iterator++ and iterator == (or !=)

Comment: @shayst Did you compare both with -O3 and with debug symbols removed ?

Comment: @shayst You'd have to look very closely at the entire process and the code produced to see what's going on. There's no one obvious thing that it's got to be.

Comment: @Arunmu We use by default high optimization levels for all our code (optimize for size), and of course we strip debug symbols.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'll also try to see the files post processed and check the results. Good idea!

Comment: Accepting this answer (albit a little late). Apparently, the extra checks and some extra code I had in some hidden place caused the size overhead. Eventually we did manage to save a some space with our internal implementation instead of using the original STL.